# How to match specific string in Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to take away characters from such type of string:

```
\xa0(Geändert am 01.Aug. 2013)
\xa0(Geändert am 05.Dez. 2014)
```

to keep only : `01.Aug. 2013, 05.Dez. 2014`

So as far I ended up with: `[(\xa0)(Geändert)(am)]`, but it is not working properly

[image]

Comment: `s = s.replace('\xa0(Geändert am ', '').replace(')', '')`. If that is a literal text, `r'\xa0(Geändert am '` should be used in the first replace.

Comment: So where is your code ?

Comment: Please consider going to python docs and reading the following topic: [string.replace](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add some validation into regex and parse each part of the date into different capturing group, you can use [next](https://regex101.com/r/7et6c1/1) regex:

```
(([\d]{2})\.((?:J[aä]n|Feb|Apr|Aug|Sept|Okt|Nov|Dez)\.|(?:M[aä]rz|Mai|Juni|Juli)) ?([\d]{4}))
```

First group will contain full date and next three - separate parts (day, month, year).

Example:

```
import re

s = """\xa0(Geändert am 01.Aug. 2013)
\xa0(Geändert am 05.Dez. 2014)
\xa0(Geändert am 25.Juni 1995)
\xa0(Geändert am 11.März 2005)"""
pattern = r"(([\d]{2})\.((?:J[aä]n|Feb|Apr|Aug|Sept|Okt|Nov|Dez)\.|(?:M[aä]rz|Mai|Juni|Juli)) ?([\d]{4}))"

for match in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    print("Datum: {}, tag: {}, monat: {}, jahr: {}".format(*match.groups()))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string formation for the parts you want to remove is fixed you don't need regex.
i.e. just remove the first N characters and the last 1 to strip off the parts you don't need.

If you want to avoid "magic numbers" then Python string `replace` is just as good:

```
removeStart = data.replace('\xa0(Geändert am ', '')
removeEnd = removeStart.replace(')', '')
```

Failing that it's good practice to try to use regex match the parts you want to keep (i.e. match the good stuff to keep, not the bad stuff to remove), so write a pattern which matches the date string. This means that if the stuff you don't care about changes, the code still works.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
\d{2}\.\w{3}\.\s\d{4}
```

Comment: In german lang not all months names shorten to 3 chars with dot, so your example won't work on 5 months (`März`, `Mai`, `Juni`, `Juli`, `Sept.`).